# Mongoose "Find" not returning same results as Mongo Shell

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, find

I am facing a problem while using the find function from the Mongoose package. When I call the function it returns nothing. However using MongoDBCompass's shell I get the results as expected.
Here is the function call :

```
let { ISBN } = *req.body*;
let searchPattern = ISBN;

await booksModel
    .**find**({ ISBN: { $regex: searchPattern, $options: "i" } })
    .then((result) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        return res.status(200).json({ message: `${result.length} books found`, books: result });
      }, 1000);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "Error while searching.", error: error });
    });
```

The ISBN is stored as a "String" type. The queries are also made as string coming

Here is the Schema.

```
const booksSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ISBN: String,
  title: String,
  author: String,
  thumbnail: String,
  description: String,
  addDate: Date,
  additionalImages: [], // { String, String }
  storageInfo: [], // type {serialNumber: Number, aisle: String, shelf: String}
  issueList: [], // userID: String, issueDate: Date, isIssued: Boolean
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: It is difficult to determine where your problem lies. Please answer the following. 1. Why do you have asterisks around your `let { ISBN } = *req.body*;` , is that in your actual code? 2. In your code above you have `await booksModel .**find**(...);` then you have `await booksModel.find(...)`, what is going on there, is that in your actual code? 3. Can you `console.log(searchPattern )` to make sure something is actually in there? 4 Why is your `return res.status(200)` wrapped in a `setTimeout(() => {}` function? 5 Can you post your schema?

Comment: Here are the answers: 1) Not the actual code. It was intended to be made bold by the post. 2) Duplicated. Now removed the second instance. 3) Yes the ISBN is in there. 4) Created and artificial delay in the response. Will remove in the deployment. 5) Yes. I have edited my post.

Comment: @jQueeny thanks for your effort. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Bummer. I was connected to another instance of the database in my application which did not have the ISBN entries I was typing. And MongoDB Compass was connected to a different instance.  Lesson learnt.